# Unable to read file from s3 using spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a file from s3 from spark-shell. I am initiating spark-shell using the below command including the required packages.

`spark-shell --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.0.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1`

Inside spark-shell, I am initiating a spark session using the below configs.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("testhive")
.config("spark.master", "spark://xxx:8081")
.config("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access",true)
.config("fs.s3a.fast.upload", true)
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", false)
.config("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", 2)
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://asdasd.com")
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "asdadszzzxxxx")
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "xcxcxcxcxc")
.config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
```

But when i am trying to read data from s3 using

`df = spark.read.format('delta').load('s3a://path_to_s3_file")`

i am facing below error.

`Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAwsCredentialsException: SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider: No AWS credentials in the Hadoop configuration`

Thanks in Advance!